# Tampermonkey overrides JIRA Shortcuts

Tags: javascript, jira, tampermonkey

I have a tampermonkey script which colorizes JIRA comments depending on their  text. The coloring does work as expected. But **all** keypress events of the JIRA issue are deactivated.

Before the script I was able to press `.` to activated the Action Menu or press `m` to add a comment etc.

After the script nothing works.

*Info*: When I run the script within Chrome's Snippet Windows everything is fine - all shortcuts still work and the coloring has happened. That lets me assume that Tampermonkey kind of overrides or unbinds the key-events in JIRA.

Anybody an idea how to avoid this?

**script**

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         JiraCommentColors
// @namespace    com.company.tamperscripts
// @version      0.2
// @description  colorize comments in JIRA made by awesome xetra11
// @author       xetra11
// @match        https://jira.company.com/browse/*
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    var opacity = '0.3';
    var borderStyle = '1px solid black';
    var commentSelector = "div[id*='comment']";
    var zwischenstandSelector = 'a[name=Zwischenstand]';
    var fragenSelector = 'a[name=Frage]';
    var wartenSelector = 'a[name=Warten]';
    var colorZwischenstand = 'rgba(0, 102, 0, '+ opacity +')';
    var colorFrage = 'rgba(0, 153, 204, '+ opacity +')';
    var colorWarten = 'rgba(255, 102, 0, '+ opacity +')';

    var paintZwischenstand = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorZwischenstand)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };
    var paintFrage = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorFrage)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };
    var paintWarten = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorWarten)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };

    $(zwischenstandSelector).each(paintZwischenstand);
    $(fragenSelector).each(paintFrage);
    $(wartenSelector).each(paintWarten);
})();
```

Comment: I tried the same script on JIRA and it's working fine. I'm using TM 4.2.7. What version of TM you're using?

Comment: You're probably using older version. See [Tampermonkey 'hijacks' cmd+shift+e](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=2123&sid=404affd8d05611dc689e0e2b83eb8dfd) bug.

Comment: 4.3.6 is my version. 
Can u use JIRA shortcuts like Pressing . to open quick commands?

Comment: Yes. I tried shortcuts and it's working. Can you also try to use Tampermonkey Beta.

Comment: Just tried that - did not helped either :/

Comment: JIRA v6.4.11 is the version of JIRA FYI

Comment: I have JIRA v7.2.3. It's working fine with this version.

Comment: after tampermonkey run the script, what id you see in the console?

Comment: @xetra11 reply my comment above.

Comment: @SagarV there unfortunately isn't any console error/output if I ran the script

Comment: @xetra11 can you provide full script. I mean with the configuration section included

Comment: @SagarV updated code in question

Comment: @xetra11 the only reason I can see with this is absence of `run-at` I added an answer. Check it and let me know if the issue exists

Answer (score 3):

The possible reason may be because you didn't specified the `@run-at` to `document-end`. Try the below code

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         JiraCommentColors
// @namespace    com.company.tamperscripts
// @version      0.2
// @description  colorize comments in JIRA made by awesome xetra11
// @author       xetra11
// @match        https://jira.company.com/browse/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


(function() {
    var opacity = '0.3';
    var borderStyle = '1px solid black';
    var commentSelector = "div[id*='comment']";
    var zwischenstandSelector = 'a[name=Zwischenstand]';
    var fragenSelector = 'a[name=Frage]';
    var wartenSelector = 'a[name=Warten]';
    var colorZwischenstand = 'rgba(0, 102, 0, '+ opacity +')';
    var colorFrage = 'rgba(0, 153, 204, '+ opacity +')';
    var colorWarten = 'rgba(255, 102, 0, '+ opacity +')';

    var paintZwischenstand = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorZwischenstand)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };
    var paintFrage = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorFrage)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };
    var paintWarten = function(index, element){
        $(element).closest(commentSelector)
            .css('background-color', colorWarten)
            .css('border', borderStyle);
    };

    $(zwischenstandSelector).each(paintZwischenstand);
    $(fragenSelector).each(paintFrage);
    $(wartenSelector).each(paintWarten);
})();
```

Comment: Awww I hoped thats the solver. But it did not do nothing. I also tried `document-idle` but no luck either...

Comment: can you make a small screen cast of the working, including console?

Comment: How can I screencast a shortcut-press? I can screenshot you the console output

Comment: Ah sorry for that. I am in a little sleepy mode.try to cast the console output.

Comment: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=221642-1498500354.jpg - same console output as without the script FYI

Comment: looks like a lot of issues are present in batch JS.

Comment: As I said they appear even without the script and do not affect shortcut functionality

Comment: @xetra11 can you check the body or document in inspect element -> event listeners for any existing event listener

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147731/discussion-between-xetra11-and-sagarvd).

Comment: @xetra11 can you check the browser version?

Comment: @xetra11 please reply to the above comment